# Move Sharepoint 2010 Lists from development environment to production

Tags: list, templates, sharepoint-2010, workflow, move

I have a development Environment set up with the easysetup Powershell script from Microsoft.
On the development Environment I created Lists based on different Content types.
Now it is time to get my results to the production environment but I am having problems, moving my lists to production.
I already saved the lists as list templates, exported them out of the dev environment. Afterwards I tried to import them on the production environment successfully. But I am not able to create new lists based on the templates because I they are not shown in the "Create" dialog. 
Is there any way to get my list templates displayed or is there another way to get objects like lists, site columns, content types and workflows from development to production?